# Firebase: How to avoid nested callbacks?

Tags: android, firebase, callback, firebase-realtime-database

Based on the official Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) it's suggested to structure data in this sort of a format:

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Here's my understanding of the callback flow (By callback I refer to **onDataChange** of **addValueEventListener/addListenerForSingleValueEvent**)

```
Callback for -groups-
....In a loop Callback for each of the members (to get details from -users- node)
........Another Callback if -users- has a field for which data is at a different node
```

And so on and so forth.

Can this sort of a structure lead to a nested callback scenario, if yes, how to avoid it ?

Comment: It is quite common to have nested callbacks, although I've seldom seen it go further than 3 levels. Nested callbacks are not a problem in themselves. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm just trying to design the database so that there are fewer calls for the user for a better experience...but in order to achieve this data repetition has to happen

Comment: Duplicating data is very common in NoSQL databases. I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, will definitely go through this!

Comment: Nested call back can be avoid by using this library. https://github.com/crawlinknetworks/android-promise